# Мягкость Н в сочетаниях НЧ, НЩ

Tags: орфография

Действительно ли в сочетаниях НЧ, НЩ согласный звук *н* - всегда мягкий? Если это правило без исключений, то у меня возникает еще два дополнительных вопроса :

1. Для чего в географическом названии Маньчжурия (а также в других словах китайского происхождения) пишется мягкий знак.
2. Фамилия Меньщиков - ошибочное написание или традиция.

Comment: Предполагаю, что:

1) в названии страны "Маньчжурия" символ "ь" используется и в качестве  диакритического знака ("смягчителя") и в качестве разделителя,

2) в названии государства "Маньчжоу-го" символ "-" используется в качестве разделителя.

Comment: Уточнение. **Основной вопрос** : всегда ли **н** в сочетаниях НЧ и НЩ является мягким согласным звуком или может оставаться твердым, как **л** в словах *молча*, *галчонок*, *колчан*...

Маньчжурию списываем на особенности транскрипции разных китайских Н; написание *Меньщиков* - на семейные традиции различения с Менщиковыми. Вот еще *гданьчане* под ногами путаются)

Подкину чуток материала : топонимы Мончегорск, Конча-Заспа, фамилии Бонч-Бруевич, Кранчар. Все **н** - мягкие?

Comment: А я напомню, что язык обезьяны вида Homo sapiens можно рассматривать как мышцу, которая:

- либо находится в сокращенном состоянии (например, при произнесении звука "[ш:ь]"),

- либо находится в расслабленном состоянии (например, при произнесении звука "[ш]").

Comment: Узнаю Ивана **по походке**))) Фамилию он носит - да, Стрельцов!!!

Comment: Моё настоящее имя Галактион. Вместе с тем, не буду отрицать, что между мной, Иваном Стрельцовым, Алексеем Шахматовым, Андреем Колмогоровым, Валентином Серовым, Михаилом Кутузовым-Голенищевым и т. п. есть кое-что общее.

Comment: Заметано) А че Вас тут минусуют всю дорогу?

Comment: Предполагаю, что некоторые userы сердятся на меня.

Comment: ну, это понятно - что минусуют, из-за того что сердятся. А вы не можете предположить, за что именно сердятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, Вы правы по поводу фамилии Меньщиков, а насчет Маньчжурии предполагаю, что китайское название выглядело примерно так: Мань Чжу...

Comment: Прискакал на мохнатой монгольской лошадке - цок, цок, цок - маньчжур из далеких степей на Украйну, женился на хохлушке и пошли у них дети... ("Як з'явилося прізвище Манжура")))

Answer (score 3):

"Маньчжурия" - от того, имхо, что в китайском два звука Н - носовой и обычный. Последний как правило передается на русском через НЬ. В английском наоборот, носовой передается через NG.
Посмотрите систему Палладия. К мягкости/твердости звуков в русском отношения не имеет.

Что касается Меншикова (со всеми варинтами), то скорее всего и тут вопрос мягкости/твердости не стоит.
Написание имен собственных часто закреплено традицией и не всегда точно можно сказать, насколько у этой традиции есть историческое объяснение. 
Надо тщательно проанализировать и сопоставить ряд моментов. Когда закрепилось именно такое написание фамилии, когда отвердели в русском шипящие, был ли там ерь в старом написании - и вообще точно ли фамилия происходит от "меньшой", а не от созвучного слова (такое тоже бывает) и не от диалектного произношения (это самое верное, ибо подобное произношение, если не ошибаюсь, свойственно аж старопетербуржскому говору).

Мне все это делать откровенно лениво, результат все равно будет нулевым или малозначимым. Ибо, как сказал бы один недоброй памяти персонаж, "свойствам русского языка не противоречит". В смысле - твердое произношение.

Comment: Касательно меньшиковых есть 4 варианта: Меншиков(а), Менщиков(а), Меньшиков(а), Меньщиков(а).